# How to find the closest label to an input element where they are on the same level

Tags: jquery, html

I'm dynamycally adding `input` elements to my form. Each logical code block looks like this:

```
<input .. />
<input .. />
<label></label>
```

and the idea of the `label` is to display error message, in this case, if on of the two inputs is empty I want to show message the both inputs are required.

Here is a JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a2ucm7r7/). walking through this step by step I think that I successfully get each `input` and perform the check but then I'm not able to get the `label` so I can add the appropriate text. And it's important that I get the closest `label` after the input, because I want to use one label for both inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *label* is a sibling of *input*, You need to use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

*Use*

```
$(v).next('label').text("Both fields are required!");
```

instead of

```
$(v).find('label').text("Both fields are required!");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/a2ucm7r7/1/)

Comment: once the input is done, still validation is appearing which is wrong

Comment: @Amit, I am sure OP will handle that now.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks for the answer. It's working. Amit, yeah in my original code I'm taking care of it, here I just wanted to find a way to get the next label, the other things were irrelevent so I don't add them to my demo.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(v).nextAll('label').eq(0).text("Both fields are required!");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2ucm7r7/3/)

```
$(v).next('label').text("Both fields are required!");
```

if the First Name is empty, .next('label') won't work.