# jQuery DOM navigation - find next label after checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom

This should be easy, but I'm really stuck.

I have a table element that's populated with an asp.net repeater. My user checks one or more checkboxes and my jQuery loops through them to find the related label text. I had this working, but I changed the organization of my table, and now I can't seem to get it working again.

My HTML:

```
<table class="c _table">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="c_imgPlusMinus" ImageUrl="Images/plus.jpg" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkConAll" runat="server"/>Select Data
        </th>      
    </tr>    
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td >
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" cssclass="cd_chk" /><asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DataName") %>' /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>                  
</table>
```

My jQuery:

```
var wholeString= '';
$('.cd_chk :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    wholeString = $(this).next('label').text();

    (do some stuff with wholeString)

});
```

But I've been monkeying around with this for an hour or more, and I can't seem to pick up the text from that label in the repeater.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520824/how-to-find-the-closest-label-to-an-input-element-where-they-are-on-the-same-lev) was where I got the syntax in this post ($(this).next('label').text();), but neither this nor anything else I've tried seems to work.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Per suggestion, here is the actual markup produced by my code. The repeater produced two rows:

```
<table class="c_analyte_table">
<tr>
<th>
<img class="c_imgPlusMinus" src="Images/plus.jpg" />
</th>
<th>
<input id="chkConAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptConventionals$ctl00$chkConAll" />
Conventionals 
</th>      
</tr>    
<tr class="cd_chemRow">
<td >
</td>
<td>
<span class="cd_chkLab"><input id="" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptConventionals$ctl01$ctl00" /></span><span>Total Suspended Solids, Particulate</span> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cd_chemRow">
<td >
</td>
<td>
<span class="cd_chkLab"><input id="" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptConventionals$ctl02$ctl00" /></span><span>Total Suspended Solids, Total</span> 
</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: wholeString = wholeString = $(this).next('label').text(); <--- what are you trying to do here?

Comment: try `$(this).parent('td').find('label').text();`, and yes as per above comment, looks like something wrong with the assignment

Comment: @Amit.rk3, Nope, didn't work. That's one of the things I tried, and I think it should work, but it gives me a blank string.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML, typo in my question. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Label` control is rendered as `span` HTML element. It is only when this control has a property `AssociatedControlID` set that it renders as actual `label`.

You do not have this property set, so querying for `label` won't give you anything at all. You need to query for `span`.

Also take into account that `Checkbox` renders into `<span><input></span>`, so the input element itself has no siblings, you need to get to its parent first.

All in all:

```
wholeString = $(this).parent().next('span').text();
```

Another solution, perhaps simpler one, would be to assign some class to the Label. It does not need to be defined in any CSS, as it will serve as a distinction for querying only. For example, you could say:

```
<Label CssClass="checkboxLabel" .../>
```

the query would independent from details of ASP.NET rendering engine:

```
wholeString = $(this).parent('td').find('.checkboxLabel').text();
```

Comment: That didn't work either, although I'm sure your right about 'span'. That's what I had the jQuery about a year ago, which worked, but I couldn't remember why I used 'span'. I'll remember that, thanks, but I'm still getting a blank string for wholeString.

Comment: @Stanton, strange, that should have been it. Can you post the exact markup that is being generated for one of the table rows?

Comment: good suggestion, I have edited the question to show the actual markup produced by my code.

Comment: Odd... my code seems to be producing an extra closing span tag. Could that be it? And can anyeone think where that's coming from?

Comment: @Stanton, there is no extra closing span. You have checkbox input wrapped in span, and then another span after it. That explains why `next` does not work, as checkbox has no siblings. Try that:  `$(this).parent().next('span').text();`

Comment: That was it, problem solved. If I can pick your brain one last time, what is that first span (the one around the checkbox) doing there? I don't see that my code is doing that... do checkboxes automatically get wrapped in a span, or is it something I'm not seeing in my code?

Comment: Yes, this is what ASP.NET adds when you use `Checkbox`. Server-side controls generally do not correspond to a single HTML element, so don't make such assumptions.